# Aerospike Nozzle Geometry

Tags: rocket-science

I have searched the site and my search for the results I want yielded 16 results, none of which seemed to be very helpful. I have searched the internet several times but I do not have the knowledge or time to read an entire 110 page article about aerospike nozzles that may not have what I need in it. I have a science fair in a month and need to be able to successfully design an aerospike rocket nozzle, and run it through CFD.

Where may I get the equations required to calculate my aerospike nozzle geometry, and do certain characteristics such as the nozzle "throat area" from a typical bell nozzle carry over to the new design? I would understand if this design process is much more involved, but I have been able to find sites previously like [Richard Nakka's Rocketry Site](http://www.nakka-rocketry.net/) on the topic of solid rocket nozzle design and that has given me invaluable resources on that topic. I also understand that aerospike nozzles are not as widely used in the industry and resources may be more scarce. I just need to be able to design one.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=rocket+nozzle+Aerospike+

Comment: See? 15 results, and not one about the design of Aerospike nozzles. There is a question on here about de Laval Nozzle geometry, however.

Comment: I ran into this recently. Not sure if it would be useful for what you're doing:
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1757-899X/247/1/012008/pdf